# Can someone take a look at the code I'm using to generate iAds - Works when testing but not live

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect, iad

It's been two weeks now since my first app was approved, it has been downloaded over a hundred times. In this app I have an iAd banner on the bottom of the screen, the thing is that I'm able to see ads when I compile and run form Xcode but if I download the app from the app store it doesn't show any ads.

This is what I have as far as code and Xcode configuration.

**Framework:**
iAd.framework

Views
I have an Ad BannerView connected to the viewContoller (delegate).

**.h file**

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
```

**.m file**

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
}
```

**iTunes Connect:**
In iTunes Connect I filled out the contract, tax and banking information. The only thing I noticed is that in the Tax Information section I checked the Subject to Backup Withholding: check box instead of the Exempt Payee. Could this be the issue?

I contacted Apple and this is what they responded.

> Hello,
>
> We see that your app is eligible to receive live ads from the iAd App
>   Network, however your app is generating zero ad requests. We need to
>   see ad requests so that the iAd App Network can attempt to fill them
>   with a paid ad. Ad requests are entirely a function of your
>   application.  Please review the useful resources below to ensure you
>   have the proper iAd code implementation in place:
>   - iAd Programming Guide, in the iOS Dev Center > iOS Developer Library > iAd
>
> - iAdSuite sample code, in the iOS Dev Center > iOS Developer Library > iAd
> - iAd Implementation Best Practices Technical Note: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2264/_index.html
>     For code-level assistance, please contact Apple Developer Technical
>     Support (DTS) by submitting an iOS Developer Technical Support
>     Request:https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/submit/. Best
>     Regards,    iAd App Network Support Apple, Inc. 1 Infinite Loop
>     Cupertino, CA 95014

Any idea what am I doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Is there any other option in iTunes Connect that I should turn on or something in my code that needs to be modified?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried distributing the app for AdHoc and see whether iAd is working there? Maybe it just works with the debug profile. Hope this helps...

Comment: No I have not, I will try that but I'm not really sure what this will tell me. If it works under Ad Hoc, will that mean that my code will need to be modified?

Comment: You said the views you have the iAd banners in.  Do you have multiple views with iAds?  If you do, you need to make one instance of the iAd banner and use that throughout the app.  One method is to make the ad in the app delegate and use that one throughout the entire app.  Search for using shared instance of ADBannerView across app with UITableViews.  Perhaps it will help.

Comment: Yes, I do have multiple views showing iAds  I will give that a try. Thanks a lot.